# Can I do a geospatial query in MongoDB that uses location and region data from the same document?

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I want to do a geospatial query with MongoDB but I want to check using the location and region with values from the same record.  For example, assume the following record:

```
{ 
    "username" : "someUser", 
    "location" : {
        "geometry" : {
            "type" : "Point", 
            "coordinates" : [ 80.0, 8.0 ]
        }
    }, 
    "region" : {
        "_id" : "regionId", 
        "location" : {
            "type" : "Feature", 
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Polygon", 
                "coordinates" : [ 
                    [ 40.0, 5.0 ], 
                    [ 100.0, 0.0 ], 
                    [ 100.0, 10.0 ], 
                    [ 40.0, 10.0 ], 
                    [ 40.0, 5.0 ]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is to find all the documents where the user's location is within the region polygon, both of which are described in the same document.  I assumed it would be something like this:

```
db.myCollection.find({
    "location.geometry": { 
        $geoWithin: {
            $geometry: "$regions.location.geometry"
        }
    }
});
```

However, that results in an error:

```
    "errmsg" : "unknown geo specifier: $geometry: \"$regions.location.geometry\"",
```

So the problem seems that you are not allowed to provide a field path to the $geometry value.  Not sure if I've got some syntax wrong (I tried a number of things), or whether this type of search if simply forbidden/not supported.  Or perhaps it's simply a limitation of the geospatial operations.

Comment: You need to use the `.aggregate()` method

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Do you have an example of how to use the aggregate() pipeline to do this?  I have looked at it myself but wasn't able to determine the stages that would provide a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately mongodb doesn't allow to perform queries comparing with other attributes in the same document, unless you use a JS function.

Is this a database you are developing or just consuming?
Does the location or the region change very often for a user?
I ask because you should consider that this kind of query is going to perform a full collection scan, since it'll need to evaluate the $geoWithin function on each document. And that won't be very efficient.

I would suggest to determine if the location is within the polygon (or not) during any Upsert operation, then store that boolean result in a separate attribute (let's call it 'is_within') in the same document and add an index on that new attribute. This way the query will be very efficient regardless the size of the collection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I was hoping I was doing it wrong rather than it can't be done ;-)

We are developing the database.  The location changes frequently, the region less so but it can still change.  The upsert isn't an option for us but I may look at the JS function approach even if it's non-performant as the data sets may not be that large and it would be better to be slow than not have it at all.